# Video chatting in Java Servlet

Tags: java, servlets, webrtc

I am trying to find a way to transmit a user's video+audio stream(captured by client side webrtc and streamed to a html5 video element)to another client in the context.Is there a way to accomplish this like getting the bob's stream(request.getInputStream)and write that bytes to alice's response output stream and vice versa so that bidirectional streaming is possible?

Comment: Yes it is possible. What have you tried?

Comment: I'm also interested in this.

Comment: @PeterRader I can capture audio and video by webrtc on the client side.Server side..I havent done much yet but I think of saving requests or sessions in a context scoped map like Map<Request,Response> or something like that.Is it possible?

Comment: A request/response is different from streaming. You could use Video-over-IP. I see a server in proxying the streams or even just connect the streams between the clients and keep the server detached in the final conversation.

Comment: Also a compression of the video/audio should be used for some who have slow bandwich.

Comment: @PeterRader cant responses and requests hold stream bytes? Why they are different from streaming?

Comment: @Pax May sound like a basic question but you basically want to do a video call or conference or broadcast?

Comment: @ObscureGeek I want to implement random video chat like chatroulette in servlets.I know it can be done over sockets,node.js etc.Basically I can capture audio + video by webrtc and I want to transmit these streams between clients so they can see and hear other client and vice versa.So I want to know,is there a way to save a user in a context and so server can send response bytes receive request bytes at anytime?

Comment: @Pax Why do you want to make it a client server based implementation when WebRTC can easily do what you want peer to peer? Is there some server side processing on the stream? Or you basically want to send the same stream to some other user later, in other words is your expectation real time communication?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if I truly understand what you want to achieve, but let me try.

1. UserA 'getsMediaUsers' and has access to camera and audio feed
   ( and so does UserB)
2. You want to send these streams between UserA and UserB so they can see and hear each other.

Now, webRTC has nothing to do with the stream capture. But it has everything to do with streaming it p2p between UserA and UserB without the need for an intermediate server(at least as long as the initial connection is achieved).

See example here: https://apprtc.appspot.com/ . In this example a number of users enter a room and see and hear each other. If you want to implement a chat roulette you can take this functionality and do it.

Comment: Getting user media on the browser is a part of webrtc technology(https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/getUserMedia for instance).What I want to do is sending a user's stream which is captured by browser,to the server side(java servlet) and so server can transmit to another peer and reverse.So like a stream bridge is established between peers.

Comment: Quick question: why send the stream to the server to act as a bridge? You can connect the users p2p.